# shared hosting .htaccess within primary domain .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm sorry for what can be considered a confusing title; but thought of no alternative. And I need to know how .htaccess on a primary level of multiple level file three system level affects the behavior of the .htaccess files of the levels below; as well as how .htaccess files from the other levels affect behavior within the non-primary domains.

I am hosting multiple websites from a shared hosting account.

Assume cpanel file three system structure.

From public_html I have the primary domain, this directory contains a .htaccess file. Then, down the three file structure I have other domains, which I will refer to as secondary domains, and each has its own .htaccess

if a secondary domain has no .htacess, the .htaccess from the primary domain affects the behavior of url's of domains down the file three structure.

I want to ensure that all www.domain.com go to domain.com (at least from my current service provider; because, I was with another and this was not the case. .htaccess from whatever level do not affect others)

I wanted to redirect www.domain.com to domain.com

The primary level .htaccess achieves my goal for the primary domain through the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.primarydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://primarydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And I have trial and error for secondary domain trying to achieve the same with code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.secondarydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://secondarydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

WITHIN the .htaccess that is within the primary domain leve, and the second level of the file three sytem and I am unable to get the desired result

For better ilustration I add a three file system:

```
cpanel_account

   public_html
      .htaccess
      index.php
      index.html
      secondarydomain.com
         .htacess
         index.php
         index.html
```

How can I redirect www.secondarydomain.com calls to secondarydomain from the .htaccess whether primary domain level or secondary domain level of the file three structure?

Thank you,

[UPDATE]

Well, good I posted the question b/c now that I do more research I find:

as i look over the .htaccess of one of one shared hosted account i found the following modified .htacess code for first level public_html

```
# -FrontPage-
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName PrimaryDomain.com
AuthUserFile /home/USER/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/USER/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp

<files *.js.gz>
  AddType "text/javascript" .gz
  AddEncoding gzip .gz
</files>
<files *.css.gz>
  AddType "text/css" .gz
  AddEncoding gzip .gz
</files>
RewriteEngine on
#Check to see if browser can accept gzip files.
ReWriteCond %{HTTP:accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Safari
#make sure there's no trailing .gz on the url
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.+\.gz$
#check to see if a .gz version of the file exists.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
#All conditions met so add .gz to URL filename (invisibly)
RewriteRule ^(.+) $1.gz [QSA,L]
```

And **whether I add or not** this code to second levels domain level (i.e. public_html/secondarydomain.com/.htacess)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.secondarydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://secondarydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

(REPEAT WHETHER I ADD THIS CODE OR NOT)

the domains, all domain requests (i.e. www.anyofmydomainshostedhere.com) are redirected to non-www anyofmydomainshostedhere.com

:?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the goal correctly, you need to place the secondarydomain.com rewrite in the secondarydomain.com folder. The reason for this is that the domain is directed immediately to the folder and never sees the .htaccess file in the public_html folder.

I'm not too positive about the cascading .htaccess thing you mentioned - that'd be a rather interesting server configuration and I've got no clue how that would work since .htaccess is supposed to be directory-level.

Comment: YOU UNDESTOOD me perfectly, the cascading term fits like a shoe. But take for example, I asked the hosting service provider about the redirect of www to non www, and then the modified .htaccess appeared on the primary domain (looked at updated post, b/c comment area does not allow for good formatting of text) so, in my case cascading is absolutelly happening UNLESS you tell me otherwise from the update above

Comment: I'm confused. Is the code you posted in the update, except the last block, your entire .htaccess file? It may be that your hosting company changed something in the server settings or httpd.conf. I'm not exactly sure what's happening at this point, but I don't believe that .htaccess rules should be applied recursively.

Comment: yes, the code posted in the update, except the last block is placed in the first level of my hosting account (i.e. public_html/.htaccess) AND this appeared after I asked the hosting company about my redirects not working. As i was reading from apache/.htacess specs I understand that the server administrator can set limitations for down the three file .htaccess behavior; or what you so rightly termed "cascading" http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: I'm not sure where to go from here because your hosting company could've done any number of things. If the redirects are working, I wouldn't worry much about it. If they aren't, reply here again and I'll work with you to get them set straight.